# File Pattern _* not being recognized

Tags: regex

I need to process a file and it's working, but I need to change the file pattern. This is what it needs to be: `someText_XYZ_*.dat`

I added the asterisk so everything after the `_` is accepted, however a file with this name is not being accepted: `someText_XYZ_abc1.dat`

The patterns are stored in an Oracle table. When I run the application the table is be read and the file pattern is used to match the name of the file (possibly in Apache Camel). Examples that currently work are: `.*.csv` and `[0-9]{7}.abc.*.csv`

What is wrong with my new pattern?

Comment: Are you doing a `LIKE` match on that pattern? Because LIKE matches don't use `*` as the wild card. Also, [underscore (`_`) has special meaning in LIKE matches.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm)

Comment: I imagine you want `%` not `*`

Comment: I'm checking now guys, the code is not mine, give me a sec. Thanks for the help

Comment: How can we make suggestions/give guidance if you won't even know your table structure, data and or expected results.. Or even a query  for that matter... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't think it's using LIKE because there are other cases like `.*.csv` so the star works. I'm not sure how it's processing the string gotten from the table that has the file pattern. That's done somewhere in another library and probably using apache camel. Where can I learn about the options related to this so I can test a couple?

Comment: So I have a file locally or on the server, I have a table with some info like pooling directory and file pattern to be able to recognize the right file. Once I run the app, this table would be read and gotten the file pattern to match the name of the file. This is one example that currently works: `[0-9]{7}.abc.*.csv`

Comment: If I put a `.` instead of a `_` it works, but I need the `_`

Comment: Please don't put additional information about the question into comments. Instead, please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the question tags. If you put information in comments they will very likely not be seen, and answers will be generated based on inaccurate or incomplete information. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis understood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is one example that currently works: `[0-9]{7}.abc.*.csv`

Then it seems to be a regular expression pattern; in which the periods match any character. If you want those to match actual periods in the file name them you pribably need to escape them (unless whatever is doing the processing is doing something weird): `[0-9]{7}.abc.*\.csv` or `[0-9]{7}\.abc.*\.csv` or `[0-9]{7}\.abc\..*\.csv` depending on the actual file names you want to match against.

Your new pattern has `someText_XYZ_*.dat` which will match `someText_XYZ` followed by any number *of underscores* followed by any single character followed by `dat`.

You probably want:

```
someText_XYZ_.*.dat
```

or more likely:

```
someText_XYZ_.*\.dat
```

which matches `someText_XYZ_` (including a single underscore at the end) followed by any number of any characters (from `.*`) followed by the literal `.dat`.

There are lots of resources for learning about regular expressions; [here's one](https://www.regular-expressions.info/), or a [cheatsheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) if you're impatient.

Comment: Perfect bro, thank you very much, that worked. Please correct it in your answer. This was the final result: `someText_XYZ_*\.dat` so I can accept the answer

Comment: The pattern in your comment still matches any number of underscores, followed by a literal `.dat`; not any characters between the underscore and `.dat`?

Comment: well the whole point is to accept any character between the `_` and the `.dat`

Comment: Yes, that's why the pattern in your previous comment doesn't look right.

Comment: I see, let me try yous and test some cases

Comment: @arturo: if you're going to work with regular expressions you might want to [work through some introductory free training on them](https://regexone.com/) in self defense. :-)

Comment: @AlexPoole I see what you mean now, I wrote it as you mentioned (`someText_XYZ_.*\.dat`), works perfect. Thank you, I appreciate it

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks, I need that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
'someText\_XYZ\_%.dat' ESCAPE '\'
```